# Let H be a Hilbert space and $T\in L(H)$ and we have a default operator...

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I am self studying functional analysis and I was not able to solve this particular problem in on of my assignments.

So, I am asking for help here.

> Let H be a Hilbert space and $T\in L(H)$ satisfies $||T||\leq 1$. Suppose that $D= \sqrt{1- T^* T}$. Show that for $x\in H : ||x||^2 = ||Tx||^2 +||Dx||^2$.

Attempt: $D= \sqrt{1- T^* T}$ implies that there exists an operator R , such that $D^2= R^2= 1- T^* T $ which is equivalent to $D^2 x= x- T^* Tx$ which is equivalent to $D^2 x + T^* T x =x$, but I am not able to move towards $||x||^2 = ||Tx||^2 + ||Dx||^2$.

Can you please help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ \langle D^{2}x, x \rangle =\langle x, x \rangle-\langle T^{*}Tx, x \rangle=\|x\|^{2}-\|Tx\|^{2}$. Since  $D$ is positive (hence, self-adjoint) the left side is $\|Dx\|^{2}$.

Comment: Thank you very much!